# Django Get Value from dropdown where multiple options can be selected

Tags: python, html, django, django-models

This is my form. The user can select multiple options. I dont know how to pass the form data to my view.

```
             <form method="POST">
               
             <div class="form-group" action="/">
                 <select class="mul-select" multiple="true" onchange="fun()">
                     <option value="Cambodia">Cambodia</option>
                     <option value="Khmer">Khmer</option>
                     <option value="Thiland">Thiland</option>
                     <option value="Korea">Korea</option>
                     <option value="China">China</option>
                     <option value="English">English</option>
                     <option value="USA">USA</option>
                 </select>
             </div>
             <input type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary" value="Select">
             </form>
```

This is my view

```
from .models import Countries
  def savedata(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
       
        if request.POST.get('value'):
            saveresults = Countries()
            saveresults.country = request.POST.get('value')
            saveresults.save()
         
            return render(request, 'index.html')
    else:
        return render(request, 'index.html')
```

My  `request.POST.get('value')` is returning None.

Comment: I believe you need to put a `name` attribute on the `<select>` element, and use that name in your `.get()` call.

Comment: Yes I missed the name attribute and also I have to use .getlist() because I am receiving multiple option values.